# How to minimize my jQuery script

Tags: jquery

I'm working on simples actions from jQuery Library.

```
$('#hasAccount').click(function() {
        $('.authForm').slideDown(500, function() {
            if ($('.shippingAddress').is(':visible')) {
                $('.shippingAddress').slideUp(250);
            }
        });
});

$('#hasNotAccount').click(function() {
        $('.shippingAddress').slideDown(500, function() {
            if ($('.authForm').is(':visible')) {
                $('.authForm').slideUp(250);
            }
        });
});
```

Here is the code working : http://jsfiddle.net/6tZQ2/2/

It's very simple, but I'm wondering if there are any solutiosn to minimalize this script as 1 action ?

Thanks :-)

Comment: is there any practical usage? or is it more code-golfing? if you so, you may want to include this tag!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

http://jsfiddle.net/6tZQ2/16/

Comment: I'd say this is the most efficient answer given sofar (not running multiple $() searches on the same element). Only thing I'll say is that I'd do $('#hasAccount, #hasNotAccount') instead of $('input[name="account"]') as it's more specific (will always only iterate over those two elements) and id selectors are more efficient in general.

Answer (score 0):

You could use slideToggle and lose the if statements

Comment: Yes but with slideToggle you can close your box with a radio button checked :-(

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go - although there are a millions ways to do this better/nicer/more compact... this is the quickest in my mind... :/

http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/6tZQ2/3/

[edit] Although - this is `name` attribute based - so probably better to do it another way :)

Comment: Neuro, do you think I can use hasClass() for your compacted script ?

Comment: I finally used the input[name="..."] attribute. Thanks :o)

Answer (score 0):

Try it, i'm not expert in jquery:

```
$('input[name="account"]').click(function(e) {
    if(e.target.id == 'hasAccount') {
        $('.authForm').slideDown(500, function() {
            if ($('.shippingAddress').is(':visible')) {
                $('.shippingAddress').slideUp(250);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('.shippingAddress').slideDown(500, function() {
            if ($('.authForm').is(':visible')) {
                $('.authForm').slideUp(250);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about encompassing both functions in a more general dom.